# Liquibase installation does not give the correct version in centos7

Tags: java, liquibase

I have installed liquibase 4.3.2 version. But after setting the path and when I run `liquibase --version`, it gives the below as the version.

```
$ liquibase --version
Liquibase Version: ${project.version}
```

Same happened with 4.11.0 version.

Why don't I get the correct installed version when running `liquibase --version`?